# How do I build something to see URDF model with RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, ros-groovy, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working up a URDF file and hoping to put together a new robot model along with a tutorial describing the ROS development process.
I am using ROS-Groovy.

Right now I have a URDF that compiles and a state_publisher that fails to link.  The message reads:
"… undefined reference to 'tf::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_std::allocator<void > const&)' "

I expect that I will also need a launch file, but have no clue what it will need to contain.

First question is how do I fix this build error?

Next question is do I have the correct directory layout?
Current file organization is:

- …_ws/src/rbot_description/urdf/rbot.urdf
- …_ws/src/rbot_description/src/state_publisher.cpp

The state publisher is just a simulation stub at the moment, so knowing how to have a simulator sometimes and real control other times would be nice to know.

Finally I need to know where to put the launch file and what to put into it to get RVIZ running?

Again my assumption is that I really only need the 3 files: URDF, state_publisher and launch; is this correct?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105721/how-do-i-build-something-to-see-urdf-model-with-rviz?/) by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2013-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way would be to use the `urdf_tutorial` launch file:

`roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=/path/to/robot.urdf`

...launch rviz while loading the robot specified by the `model` argument.
You can open the file to see what is necessary and yes you need one file (the robot URDF model), the `robot_state_publisher` node, the `joint_state_publisher` node and rviz for the visualization.

This linking error should never happen for `state_publisher`. You should detail your build process in another question to solve this matter.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on 2013-11-29**:
Thank you Thomas for the response.  I will do as you say regarding the state publisher build problem.

However, there is a problem with the launch relative to the tutorial.  The error message references the .../urdf_tutorial/urdf.vcg file being the wrong format because Groovy requires a .rviz file format and Groovy does not yet have an "automated conversion program".  I can only guess what that file is good for and have no clue how to build a replacement.

I am also wondering your statement about needing a robot_state_publisher and a joint_state_publisher.  I am assuming that I need a node that publishes both pieces and it is okay to do both from within my state_publisher.cpp file?